# Лицензия MIT — разъяснение по использованию программного кода на Stack Overflow и Stack Exchange

Tags: обсуждение, лицензирование

CC-BY-SA — идеальное решение для базы знаний, наполняемой по принципу краудсорсинга, то есть безвозмездно и на добровольных началах. Применение этой лицензии принесло нам огромную пользу, благодаря ей участники сообщества смогли почувствовать себя защищенными, как результат, мы планируем и далее использовать CC-BY-SA для текстовых сообщений, публикуемых на Stack Overflow.

В случае с кодом дела обстоят немного иначе: в вопросе отношения лицензии CC-BY-SA и программного кода всегда существовала некоторая двусмысленность. Это привело к замешательству в рядах сознательных разработчиков, пытавшихся понять, чего от них требует лицензия, в случае заимствовании ими нескольких строк кода из сообщений, публикуемых на Stack Overflow. Неопределенность — враг продуктивности, как для вас, так и для нас, и мы чувствуем себя обязанными внести ясность относительно использования программного кода.

**Начиная с 1 февраля 2016 года, весь новый программный код, публикуемый на страницах Stack Overflow и шире, на Stack Exchange, будет подпадать под действие [лицензии MIT](http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT).**

Мы работаем над вопросом о лицензии уже какое-то время: мы консультировались с [OSI](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Source_Initiative), привлекали практикующего юриста и досконально обсуждали этот вопрос между собой. Мы приняли решение, которое, как мы надеемся, значительно улучшит сложившуюся ситуацию.

**Вкратце новые условия лицензирования**

Начиная с 1 февраля 2016 года, вклад участников сообщества будет регулироваться лицензией на следующих условиях:

- Вклад участников сообщества, не содержащий программного кода, будет, как и раньше, доступен для использования под свободной лицензией CC-BY-SA.
- Вклад участников сообщества в виде программного кода будет доступен для использования под лицензией MIT.
- Включать полный текст лицензии MIT в кодовую базу необязательно. Авторы кода соглашаются предоставлять пользователям кода разрешение пренебречь требованием лицензии MIT относительно необходимости размещения в коде текста лицензии в том случае, если пользователи предоставляют корректную ссылку на источник по требованию правообладателя (или сети Stack Exchange от имени автора кода). Это дополнительное исключение из условий лицензии MIT будет внесено в наше пользовательское соглашение.

Последний пункт облегчает использование Stack Exchange и предоставляет дополнительную защиту авторам и тем, кто пользуется их кодом.

Для подавляющего большинства разработчиков перечисленное выше — избыточная информация. Новые условия лицензирования ничего не меняют. Вы можете делать на Stack Overflow всё то же, что делали раньше, и, возможно, даже больше: копировать код, редактировать его, «играть» с ним, вставлять в своей проект и дорабатывать.

Но для того, чтобы вы могли застраховать свой код на будущее, мы рекомендуем вам выполнить следующие два требования (или хотя бы одно из них):

1. Добавить в ваш код комментарий, содержащий ссылку на сообщение, в котором вы нашли этот код, или
2. Соблюсти требования MIT в стандартном виде, разместив полный текст лицензии в вашем исходном коде.

Вы ведь уже используете первый вариант, верно? Это всего лишь стандартная рабочая процедура, если речь идёт о поиске кода в Интернет: комментарий с гиперссылкой дает возможность отладки кода в процессе работы. Но по новым требованиям такой комментарий, помимо удобства использования, приобретает дополнительные качества: это и благодарность автору, и «услуга за услугу», с помощью которой вы демонстрируете, что выполнили условия автора кода.

Мы с нетерпением хотим узнать ваше мнение по поводу данных изменений. Перед тем, как вы их напишете, позвольте коротко ответить на возможные вопросы:

**Это и вправду так просто?**

Да, просто. Мы стараемся найти оптимальное сочетание удобства и ясности. Новая схема дает возможность соблюсти соответствие лицензии даже при минимальном количестве действий с вашей стороны. Нужно сделать лишь одно: дать ссылку на исходное сообщение, если и когда об этом попросит его автор.

**У меня проект с открытым исходным кодом, могу ли я просто вставить в него текст лицензии MIT?**

Можете. Вы вправе воспользоваться данным исключением из требования о размещении текста лицензии в программном коде или не делать этого — решать вам. На момент вступления в силу новых требований в нашем справочном центре уже будут выложены простые и понятные инструкции о том, что делать, чтобы ваш код соответствовал требованиям лицензии, с целым рядом конкретных примеров.

**Как быть с кодом, добавленным до 1 февраля 2016 г.?**

Это только первый шаг по устранению неоднозначности в условиях лицензирования Stack Overflow и других сайтов сети Stack Exchange. Код, добавленный до 01.02.2016, будет доступен для использования на прежних условиях, по открытой лицензии CC-BY-SA. Мы ищем варианты, позволяющие нашим пользователям приспособить добавленный ранее код под новую схему.

**А как же другие сайты сети Stack Exchange?**

Указанные условия вступят в силу для кода, добавленного после 01.02.2016 для всех сайтов сети Stack Exchange.

**Кто придумал эту схему?**

Винить (как вариант, благодарить) за это нужно [Тима Поста](https://stackoverflow.com/users/50049/tim-post), [Бриттона Пэйна](http://copyrighton.com/) и [Сэма Брэнда](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/896802/). Они также активно пользовались помощью [Open Source Initiative](http://opensource.org/).

**Что дальше?**

Мы надеемся, что изменения вступят в силу 01.02.2016. Мы понимаем, что до этой даты осталось довольно мало времени, но думаем, что предлагаемые условия значительно улучшат сложившуюся ситуацию, и поэтому изменения нужно произвести как можно быстрее. Хотелось бы узнать ваше мнение по этому вопросу.

---

Это свободный перевод публикации «[The MIT License – Clarity on Using Code on Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271080/)».

Comment: Спасибо за перевод. В оригинале ещё что-то про выделение сайтов CodeReview и CodeGolf обсуждалось - с ними решили что-то? Тем более, у нас же тематика CodeReview разрешена.

Comment: @Qwertiy В оригинальное публикации про CodeReview ничего нет, про этот тип вопросов ответ. Пока ничего нового я не слышал, но обязательно уточню.

Comment: @Qwertiy Насколько я понял, народ возмутился, что лицензию резко поменяли, что не дали обсудить, что ах, ужас, катастрофа. В связи с этим переход на новую лицензию отложили на месяц, чтобы сообщество могло обсудить проблемы. Я так понимаю, следует ожидать FAQ, разбор проблем и прочее, а решение уже принято, и ничто не в силах его существенно поменять. По крайней мере, надеюсь на это, а то мутность CC утомляет.

Comment: Не в статье. Но в комментариях и вроде даже ответах было.

Comment: @Qwertiy Как только коллеги, ответственные за лицензирования сообщат что-то новое, я сразу же отпишусь. Пока что официальная позиция отображена в публикации. В любом случае, цель изменения лицензии –  упростить использование кода из вопросов и ответов сообществом. Не думаю, что есть повод для волнений.

Comment: Как будто эта лицензия тут кого-то волнует...

Comment: @Qwertiy Забивать на лицензии можно только до тех пор, пока твой код используется только на одной шестой части суши. В противном случае можно нарваться на проблемы. Скажем, у меня несколько опенсорсных проектов, которые используются весьма разным народом, поэтому лицензии для меня важны.

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что это фактически ослабление в требованиях? CC-BY-SA - обязывает указывать ссылку на исходник, тогда как MIT вообще ни к чем не обязывает. Или я не прав?

Comment: @Vartlok, да, если закрыть глаза на неоднозначность термина «лицензия mit», то это «[ослабление](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.ru.html#X11License)».

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: а в чем неоднозначность, таких лицензий несколько?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: увидел, спасибо. Добавлю в закладки.

Comment: Я так понимаю какие-то изменения произошли http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272956/a-new-code-license-the-mit-this-time-with-attribution-required?cb=1 кто-то объяснит, что нас теперь ожидает? Что обсуждение на англСО не очень веселое.

Comment: Мои знания английского не позволяют толком понять что происходит, поясните плз: сабж отменили и сейчас по-прежнему CC-BY-SA для кода что ли?