# Небольшие ошибки в разделе справки про лицензирование содержимого

Tags: дефект, статус-запланировано, справка

<s>Раздел справки «[Как лицензируются материалы, которые я публикую на сайт?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/licensing)» устарел, т.к. [код теперь лицензируется под MIT](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2265/181472).</s>

Оказалось, что код по-прежнему под CC-BY-SA.

Ещё замечания:

- последняя ссылка сломана, лишняя точка между `[]` и `()`.
- вроде бы «материалы» мы обычно переводили как «содержимое»?
- есть место для некоторых стилистических улучшений.

Пора бы его обновить. Редактируйте прямо в ответе (как это обычно происходит). Если не можете редактировать или не уверены — оставьте комментарий.

Начну с первоначальной версии, чтобы был виден diff.

Comment: Думаешь, кто-то заглядывает в вопросы с меткой [meta-tag:статус-запланировано]?

Comment: _"Оказалось, что код по-прежнему под CC-BY-SA."_ А? Что? А по-подробнее?

Comment: @Qwertiy да, я заглядываю. Это баги, которые активно обсуждаются и будут исправлены в ближайшее время.

Comment: _"я заглядываю"_ - поэтому тут и есть только твой ответ и у всего по 0 голосов? :D
PS: Поставил плюсик.

Comment: @Qwertiy спасибо ) Да, редактирование справки обычно мало кому интересно, тема не холиварная )

Answer (score 1):

## Как лицензируются материалы, которые я публикую на сайте?

Как указано в [условиях обслуживания Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com/legal) и в конце каждой страницы, вся информация, полученная от пользователя, попадает под лицензию [Creative Commons Attribution-Share Alike (CC-BY-SA)](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/). При использовании материалов с сайтов сети Stack Exchange, включая Stack Overflow на русском, [требуется обязательное указание авторства](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/).

Внимательно прочтите эти условия обслуживания и *полный текст юридического лицензионного соглашения*, чтобы узнать правила использования ваших материалов на сайте.

Comment: И что случится если в каком-то форуме будет просто ссылка, скажем, на ответ (и ничего более (или какие-то свои комментарии))?