# Под какой лицензией распространяется контент?

Tags: поддержка

[Небольшие ошибки в разделе справки про лицензирование содержимого](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2535/178988)

> <s>Раздел справки «[Как лицензируются материалы, которые я публикую на сайт?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/licensing)» устарел, т.к. [код теперь лицензируется под MIT](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2265/181472).</s>
>
> Оказалось, что код по-прежнему под CC-BY-SA.

Так что же в итоге произошло с идеей поменять лицензию?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ответ на вопрос в заголовке (Под какой лицензией распространяется контент?) находится внизу сайта:

> user contributions licensed under [cc by-sa 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)

(неплохо бы перевести эту строку, кстати).

План с лицензированием **кода** под MIT был вначале модифицирован и отложен до 1-го марта: см. [A New Code License: The MIT, this time with Attribution Required](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/272956). Переводить не стану, потому что этот план тоже был отложен на неопределённый срок, для переработки. На это решение повлияла отрицательная реакция большой части пользователей (см. рейтинг поста, на данный момент -273).

План на будущее обрисовал [Tim Post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/273377), но только в общих чертах.

Comment: Самое первое предложение в самом популярном ответе, который резко отрицательно относится к первоначальному предложению(*"Please reconsider — this is truly awful."*), говорит что MIT **менее требовательная**: [In essence, this proposal is to move from a copyleft license (CC-BY-SA 3.0) to a permissive license for code. (By default, it's basically the most permissive license possible, nearly equivalent to public domain with a liability disclaimer.)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/271113/137096)

Comment: @jfs Критика была с разных сторон. Более информированная (в популярных ответах) и менее информированная, как например в [Slashdot](http://developers.slashdot.org/story/16/01/15/1437231/use-code-from-stack-overflow-you-must-provide-attribution) -  "starting on March 1, copying code from Stack Overflow will require you to attribute that code", что отражает незнание текущего положения дел (CC BY-SA 3.0 тоже этого требует).

Comment: Вы не упомянули основную (преобладающую) позицию, что (мягко говоря) искажает позицию критиков смены лицензии на код. Представьте, что кто-нибудь сказал, что "некоторые учёные отрицают глобальное потепление" -- что технически верно, но не отражает основной позиции науки. Я решил, что стоит явно упомянуть преобладающую точку зрения по этому вопросу.

Comment: Согласен, выпячивать Slashdot не следовало. Вычеркнуто.