# Что с лицензией на код? Могу ли я поставить свою лицензию?

Tags: поддержка

Когда-то говорилось о [замене лицензии на MIT](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2265), но, как я понял со своими скудными знаниями английского и по отсутствию упоминания MIT во всяких правилах и соглашениях, потом передумали и сие изменение в силу так и не вступило.

Правильно ли я понимаю, что сейчас код по-прежнему распространяется по лицензии CC BY-SA?

Могу ли я что-нибудь сделать (дописать что-нибудь в профиль, например), чтобы распространять код моих вопросах и ответах всё-таки по лицензии MIT (в дополнение к CC BY-SA)?

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2546/178988, но НЕ дубликат из-за второй части вопроса.