# Есть ли формальные требования как следует упомянуть в своём ответе, что код взят из ответа на английском Stack Overflow и был модифицирован?

Tags: поддержка

Я вижу внизу страницы "user contributions licensed under cc by-sa 3.0 with attribution required", были [обсуждения про MIT лицензию для кода](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/285711/137096).

Какие действия следует выполнить, чтобы включить в свой ответ на Stack Overflow на русском слегка модифицированный код из Stack Overflow (английский)?

Достаточно, ли просто где-нибудь в ответе ссылку на соответствующий вопрос (даже не на ответ) привести, [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/637247/23044)?

Следует ли упоминать имя автора оригинального ответа? Следует ли ссылаться на сам ответ, а не вопрос? Необходимо ли явно упоминать, что код был изменён?

Comment: судя по тому, что _Source code on SO is still licensed under CC-BY-SA._, то достаточно добавить ссылку на источник и указать было ли что изменено

Comment: Я ничего не меня в коде. Но вопрос интересный.

Comment: Да, я считаю что ссылки на SO достаточно. В том случае, когда помощь оказывалась мне, то еще указываю ник автора. Обычно код это пример, так что указывать что код был изменен не вижу смысла

Comment: @Other если вы ничего не меняли, то ваша фраза "на основе вопроса" вводит в заблуждение. Точнее формулировка была бы "код взят из ответа". А ещё лучше кратко упомянуть суть решения и дать ссылку на код, иначе на вас ложится ответственность ошибки в коде исправлять. Версия в вашем ответе уже устарела.

Comment: @jfs, охота на ведьм - дело странное в наше время. Хотите помочь - занимайтесь реальными проблемами, а не придирками в стиле "замените формулировку, ибо эта мне не нравится".

Comment: @Other: Код,  который вы скопировали один в один устарел (содержит баг, который уже исправлен в оригинале) -- либо обновите код, либо уберите его целиком и оставьте только ссылку (если не хотите ошибки исправлять). Я указываю вам, что код, который вы опубликовали содержит ошибку. Если вы считаете это "охотой на ведьм", то технические форумы не для вас.

Comment: 1) Действительно, обновлена ошибка (?). Хотя может и просто страсть к перфекционизму. Обновлю. 2) Нельзя же делать ответ на основе чужих и **постоянно** мониторить их на наличие патча от автора? Поэтому и есть ссылка, будет глючить - перейти и посмотреть. Когда я ответил, я проверил код - без нового патча он работал вполне хорошо.

Comment: @Other: если вы не понимаете код в достаточной мере, чтобы понять содержит ли он ошибку (даже после того как она явно указана и видя исправленный код без ошибки) или если вы  не хотите *"постоянно мониторить"*, то вместо копирования один в один всего кода (более ста строк), можно было бы просто ссылку на этот Stack Overflow ответ оставить, кратко упомянув суть решения.

Comment: Вы -- делайте как хотите, главное других не трогайте.

Comment: @Other: прекратите совершать действия, которые несут вред сайту и вас никто "трогать" не будет.

Comment: Кроме Вас, меня никто не трогает, даже модераторы, а они-то лучше Вас знают что "вред для сайта". Хватит флудить.

Comment: @Other: вы  же исправили [ваш ответ уже](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/637247/23044) -- ни к чему отрицать наличие ошибки.

Comment: @jfs Пожалуйста, подскажите, как устаревание информации в ответе относится к лицензированию? Устаревание ответов – процесс естественный. Устаревший ответ следует либо исправить, либо удалить и опубликовать новый (если исправления в корне отличаются от исходного варианта). SOen и SOru на данный момент разные сайты и сообщества (участники одного сообщества не имеют доступ к аналогичным инструментам в другом). Как результат, как мне кажется, было бы здорово следовать общему правилу: минимальный пример кода и ссылка на источник соблюдая лицензию (в нашем случае CC-BY-SA).

Comment: @jfs Поясните, пожалуйста, про что именно вопрос? Про лицензирование как таковое или про то, как следует включать в свой ответ информацию со Stack Overflow на английском?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: никак не относится. Дискуссия в комментариях не относится к вопросу. Что меня интересует написано в самом вопросе (буквально). Кратко: [вот требования (4 пункта) для правильного указания ссылки на источник, если использовать информацию со SO на других сайтах](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/) -- в частности меня интересует какие из этих требований остаются, учитывая что ruSO является одним из SE сайтов. К примеру, достаточно ли (формально) только пункта №2 (Hyperlink directly to the original question) и по желанию №3 (Show the author names).

Comment: @jfs Из того, что я вижу, SOen и SOru разные сайты, как результат, я бы рекомендовал соблюдать все пункты. Более того, в пределах одного сайта (например, SOru) я бы рекомендовал делать тоже самое. Тут дело не в семействе сайтов, а в благодарности к авторам вопросов и ответов, за их время и труды.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky не могли вы для ясности на русском языке эти пункты явно в ответе привести. Насколько обязательны эти требования формально: следует ли править существующие сообщения, чтобы их удовлетворить? (К примеру,  лицензия требует упоминания была модификация или нет).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Краткие выводы для ясности на основе [@Nicolas Chabanovsky♦ ответа](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4975/23044) и комментариев:

- ["SOen и SOru разные сайты"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4897/4975?noredirect=1#comment18123_4897) — к ru.SO применяются такие же формальные требования как и любому другому интернет-сайту, который использует [en]SO содержимое (см. лицензия + специальные требования для ссылки внизу страницы). Требования не ослаблены, несмотря на то, что ru.SO принадлежит к семейству SE сайтов
- Исправлять ответы, чтобы они удовлетворяли формальным требованиям [не рекомендуется](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4897/4975?noredirect=1#comment18231_4975).  То есть на усмотрение автора ru.SO ответа, как следует и ссылаться ли вообще на [en]SO ответ.

Answer (score 5):

#### Как оформлять ссылки на сообщения других участников в рамках Stack Exchange?

На данный момент Stack Overflow на русском и Stack Overflow на английском являются разными сайтами, следовательно, ссылаясь на ответ на Stack Overflow на английском следует соблюдать общие правила:

- соблюдать лицензию источника;
- придерживаться самодостаточности ответов.

В случае со Stack Overflow необходимо соблюдение CC-BY-CA с указанием авторства, при этом ответ с одной лишь ссылкой на англоязычный сайт не приветствуется, в ответе обязательно должен быть минимальный пример решения. Более того, мы крайне рекомендуем придерживаться «джентльменского» стиля и в рамках одного сообщества – при возможности указывать авторство, в случае ссылки на ответы или вопросы других участников. Основная причина данного подхода – способ выразить благодарность авторам сообщений за проделанный труд, за все то время, которое они потратили на исследования предметной области, оформление и публикацию результатов в открытый доступ.

#### Какая лицензия используется на сайтах Stack Exchange?

На сайтах Stack Exchange действует лицензия [CC-BY-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) с [обязательным указанием авторства](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/) (это указано в подвале каждой страницы любого сайта сети Stack Exchange).

Под указанием авторства подразумевается, что в случае использования информации из сообщений, вы должны указывать автора работы в порядке установленном автором или лицензиатом. То есть:

- В ясном виде визуально показать, что контент взят с сайта Stack Overflow или другого сайта Stack Exchange.
- Разместить *прямую* гиперссылку на исходный вопрос или ответ на сайте (например, `http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/554290/6`).
- Отобразить имена авторов для каждого вопроса и ответа.
- Разместить *прямую* гиперссылку на профиль автора на сайте (например, `http://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/6/`).

«Прямая гиперссылка» - это ссылка, которая ведет непосредственно на соответствующее доменное имя с использованием стандартной HTML разметки. Пожалуйста, убедитесь, что даже с отключенным JavaScript ссылка будет видна. При размещении ссылки вы не должны использовать любую форму перенаправления (например, TinyURL). Кроме того, *ссылки не должны содержать nofollow или noindex*. Повторюсь, мы подразумеваем указание авторства в духе чести. В первую очередь, это необходимо, чтобы отблагодарить людей, которые щедро поделились своими знаниями и временем!

**Не стесняйтесь копировать, изменять и переиспользовать содержимое сайтов в свое удовольствие, не забывая указывать авторство, тем самым благодаря участников, которые создали это содержимое для сообщества!**

**MIT лицензия для кода**

Ранее [было объявление](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2265/) о переходе на новую лицензию кода (будьте внимательны, сообщения, то есть текст, под одной лицензией, код – под другой), которая подразумевает необходимость лишь ссылки на вопрос или ответ, откуда этот код был взят! На сколько я понимаю, инициатива изменения лицензии кода была отложена. То есть все содержимое сайтов распространяется под CC-BY-CA с указанием авторства.

**В заключение**

- Многие проблемы решаются более или менее стандартными подходами, как результат, разные люди могут написать одинаковый код вплоть до названия переменных (все мы учимся по одним книгам). Если ответы одинаковые, далеко не факт, что кто–то что–то у кого–то заимствовал.
- Человек не может помнить всех мест, где он узнал что–то новое, особенно по прошествию времени.
- Что есть наши новые знания? – Изучив что–то (на основе трудов других людей, например, авторов книг или ответов на сайтах), мы начинаем воспроизводить по–сути ту же информацию в своей интерпретации, которая получает новые формы. И эти формы мы считаем результатом уже наших действий, а не копированием: реализовав алгоритм сериализации, мы не добавляем копирайт «на основе третьего издания Г. Шилдта», мы считаем алгоритм результатам наших трудов!
- Многие, очень многие вещи в науке называют именами доблестных людей, которые посвятили всю свою жизнь исследованиям и поделились результатами с человечеством, в знак благодарности за их труд. Аналогичные нормы цитирования давно стали нормами общения в Интернете, да и вообще, в современном обществе.

Как мне кажется, чтобы правильно использовать лицензию Stack Exchange в большинстве случаев достаточно руководствоваться здравым смыслом и общепринятыми нормами морали.

Comment: Интересно, на использование ответов авторами вопросов(или случайными прохожими) тоже распространяется необходимость сопровождать решение ссылкой на источник? =)

Comment: @vp_arth На сколько я понимаю лицензию, да, надо ([пример](https://github.com/chabanovsky/so_association_tools/blob/master/server_app/utils.py#L4)).

Comment: @Nicolas Chabanovsky спасибо за качественное исследование и подробное разъяснение этого вопроса. В ближайшее время пробегусь по своим вопросам и добавлю авторов. А как быть, если автор вопроса на enSO удален? http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/642689/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D1%86%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-stroke-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8/642724#642724

Comment: не ту ссылку дал - на  ruSO. Вот ссылка на enSO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18206361/svg-multiple-color-on-circle-stroke/18210763#18210763

Comment: @Alexandr_T Вероятно, в этом случае авторство указывать не нужно.

Comment: 1- не могли бы вы явно все требования перечислить ("соблюдать лицензию источника" это слишком абстрактно). Пока ваш ответ одну часть (attribution) раскрыл. К примеру, я явно и неоднократно (в вопросе, в комментарии) спрашивал нужно или нет явно упоминать был ли код модифицирован? 2- С текущей практикой рекомендации в ответе не совпадает. Поэтому повторяю свой вопрос из комментария: следует ли существующие вопросы/ответы править, чтобы привести в соответствие с указанными требованиями? 3- в рамках SE сайтов ссылки на профили кажутся излишними даже когда явное упоминание автора кода оправдано.

Comment: @jfs Уточняю информацию, как только все соберу, сразу же обновлю ответ!

Comment: @jfs на мой взгляд вы частично правы,- так не хочется поднимать и править старые посты. Но ведь вопрос возник из-за  требований иностранных коллег по соблюдению авторского права в виде условий соблюдения лицензий. Согласен, с этими лицензиями, как в той пословице - "Закон, что дышло, куда повернул, так и вышло".

Comment: Насчет нужно ли, как-то отражать был ли модифицирован код, то ведь можно, как-то отразить это в комментариях прямо в коде - вот здесь ваш код, а тут моё дополнение. Я понимаю, что чисто не сделать этого,- тут моя строчка, а тут ваша - ерунда какая-то получится, но если у инстр. автора остается большой оригинальный блок и ваш код, как дополнение, то наверное всё таки возможно указывать авторство.

Comment: Насчет, что указание профиля автора ответа излишне - не согласен. Часто встречаю на enSO примеры, где на один вопрос может быть до нескольких десятков хороших ответов. Выбираю на свой взгляд лучший из них, ну в крайнем случае пару и перевожу. И в этом случае не нужно указывать автора и его профиль?. Как-то несправедливо получается. Я ставлю плюсы им там и сейчас указываю их профили.

Comment: @Alexandr_T ссылка на ответ однозначно автора определяет. Ссылка на профиль не добавляет новой информации.

Comment: @jfs пожалуйста, посмотрите более внимательно. Вопрос и ответы имеют одинаковую ссылку и это ссылка на топик с вопросом. А вот авторы ответов там могут быть разные, с разными профилями. Или я чего то не понимаю?

Comment: Кажется я начинаю вас понимать - "есть имя автора, значит авторство ответа однозначно определено", но ведь это не так. Под одинаковыми именами могут быть разные пользователи - сто пользователей "alex",  отличие только в уникальных идентификаторах, коорые как раз хранятся в ссылках на профиль пользователя.

Comment: @Alexandr_T вы заблуждаетесь: у каждого ответа своя ссылка.

Comment: @jfs вполне возможно, что у каждого ответа своя ссылка, хотя я этого, как рядовой пользователь не вижу. А как насчет одинаковых имен без указания профиля?

Comment: @Alexandr_T чтобы сомнений не было, нажмите на "поделиться" под любым ответом (ответ уникально определяет автора).

Comment: @jfs Теперь я вижу, что вы правы. Я хочу, чтобы вы правильно поняли меня. Я не сторонник спорить, чтобы только спорить, оставить последнее слово за собой и т.д и т.п. Если бы вы сразу указали на такую возможность, не было-бы столь долгой переписки. Я просто не мог понять откуда брать уникальные ссылки на пару -> ответ - профиль пользователя. В строке браузера, естественно я видел только одну общую ссылку для всех ответов.

Comment: @Alexandr_T: это ваша ответственность убедиться, что вы чушь не несёте, а не других разжёвывать в чём ваша ошибка состоит. После первого же указания на ошибку (все ошибаются -- ничего особенного), следует остановится и перепроверить ваши утверждения, а не продолжать настаивать, особенно если вы не слишком хорошо владеете темой.

Comment: @jfs Спасибо за поучения. Теперь я знаю,что к вам не стоит обращаться с вопросами.

Comment: @jfs Уточнил, но пока четкого правила о необходимости упоминания нет. Принимать решение считать код в ответе своей работой или же работой автора исходного ответа остается за пользователем. В этом случае, к примеру, если кто–то не согласен с принятым решением, я бы рекомендовал в корректной форме обсудить этот вопрос с конкретным участником в чате (или, на крайний случай, в комментариях). Править ответ, как мне кажется, в некоторых случаях может быть не этично и последствиями будут большие разногласия.

Comment: *"Пожалуйста, убедитесь, что даже с отключенным JavaScript ссылка будет видна. При размещении ссылки вы не должны использовать любую форму перенаправления (например, TinyURL). Кроме того, ссылки не должны содержать nofollow или noindex. Повторюсь, мы подразумеваем указание авторства в духе чести."* - это все лишнее. Тут движок сам найдет ссылку и оформит ее как надо.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: в случае, если вы этого не видели. Я суммировал ваш ответ и комментарии. Посмотрите, [не исказил ли я вашу точку зрения](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4998/23044)?

Answer (score 2):

Я думаю, стоит указывать источник,  при этом это и добавляет веса и позволяет проследить, было ли все понято верно (тем, кто знает английский). Отвечать просто ссылкой не стоит - они могут "протухать". Да и вопросы тут могут повторять английский сайт. Лично для себя я буду следовать принципа указания автора\источника *и* "плюсование" оригинального ответа (он же пригодился!)

Answer (score 0):

Все требования к ответу перечислил Nicolas Chabanovsky, я же попробую дать краткое руководство к действию.

Сначала должен идти перевод ответа, ведь именно он является основной частью ответа.

Далее, если того требует красота, можно вставить горизонтальную линию (`---`). А можно обойтись пустой строкой.

Далее, должна идти ссылка на оригинал. Оформлена она должна быть так, чтобы было понятно что это ссылка на оригинал, а не случайный набор буков. Ссылку надо ставить на конкретный ответ (или на вопрос - в случае перевода вопроса), в коротком формате (короткий формат - это тот, который можно получить через кнопку "share").

---

Если вы видите, что в чужом сообщении не хватает ссылки на оригинал - оставьте ее в комментарии вместо исправления чужого поста.

Оформление также принудительно исправлять и приводить к одному стилю не требуется.