# /help/referencing: добавить ссылку на соглашения принятые на русском Stack Overflow о плагиате

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено

Раздел справки [Как ссылаться на материалы, написанные другими](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/referencing) ссылается на сообщения на английской Мете:

- [Что делать, если обнаружен плагиат?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160071/137096)
- [Меня назвали плагиатором, что мне делать?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160077/137096)

где есть рекомендация **редактировать** ответ, чтобы добавить ссылки на источник, или даже нажать "тревога" (чтобы модератор **удалил** соответствующий ответ) и также присутствуют явные указания как следует ссылку на источник приводить (**до**, а не после, итд).

На Stack Overflow на русском принята [более либеральная политика](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4975/23044) (редактировать не рекомендуется, включать/не включать ли ссылки на источник и каким образом цитаты оформлять — на усмотрение автора ответа).

Предлагаю, добавить ссылку c описанием соглашений, принятых на русском Stack Overflow ([Есть ли формальные требования как следует упомянуть в своём ответе, что код взят из ответа на английском Stack Overflow и был модифицирован?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4897/23044)) в этот [раздел справки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/referencing).

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, вы предлагаете просто добавить ссылку в раздел доп. ссылок или как–то более серьезно модифицировать страницу справки? Был бы благодарен, если бы вы точно указали, какие изменения и куда стоит внести.

Comment: на усмотрение редактора. Достаточно ссылку добавить в общий список в конце. В качестве бонуса: ссылки, которые ведут на страницы на английском языке, хорошо бы, чтобы заголовки были на английском (копия из оригинала). Для полной ясности, можно [мой ответ](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4998/23044) буквально включить (если он не искажает вашу позицию) -- два коротких пункта.

Comment: Предлагаю вместе добавить все необходимые изменения, чтобы не получилось испорченного телефона!

Comment: обновил ответ .

Comment: Большое спасибо! Предлагаю подождать до понедельника, на случай если кто–то еще захочет внести правку. В понедельник обновим справочный центр.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky да, конечно. Или даже подождать пару недель (пока с домашней страницы Мета не пропадёт).

Comment: А что насчёт переводов? Обязательно ли указание ссылки на автора, или достаточно только ссылки на оригинальное сообщение? Обязательно ли размещение ссылки на оригинал **до** переведённого текста? Ведь это уже не плагиат, а производная работа. Что насчёт оформления сообщения как цитаты (требование озвучено в ссылаемых статьях на Метамете): должен ли я дословно переводить вопросы и ответы (сохраняя повествование от первого лица), или писать преамбулу *«Участник \[такой-то\](...) \[предлагает\](...) следующее решение этой проблемы: <абзац><разметка цитаты><перевод>»*? // cc: @NicolasChabanovsky

Comment: @Arhad Подскажите, пожалуйста, у вас вопрос по содержимому справочной страницы или самим правилам? То есть если вы считаете, что правила стоит уточнить, пожалуйста, не стесняйтесь вносить улучшающую правку.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, в первую очередь по самим правилам (у меня самого есть переводы вопросов и ответов, поэтому хотелось бы единообразно привести их к требованиям). Ну и по результатам да, можно уточнить этот момент в формулировке справки.

Comment: @jfs Спасибо за напоминание, добавил!

Answer (score 4):

Ниже представлена версия справочной страницы «Как ссылаться на материалы, написанные другими» для совместного редактирования.

---

[Плагиат](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%82) – публикация чужих работ без указания автора – не одобряется сообществом и может привести к голосованию против вашего ответа или его удалению.

Если вы нашли полезный ресурс, который может помочь в решении вопроса (на другом сайте или в ответе на $SiteShortName), убедитесь, что вы выполнили все следующие пункты:

- предоставьте [ссылку](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#links) на исходную страницу или ответ;
- [процитируйте](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#simple-blockquotes) только относящийся к вопросу отрывок;
- укажите имя автора исходного текста.

Не копируйте полный текст из внешних источников; вместо этого используйте их слова и идеи для поддержки своих. Всегда отдавайте должное автору текста и сайту, с которого вы его взяли, **включая прямую ссылку на исходный ресурс**.

#### См. также:

- [Есть ли формальные требования как следует упомянуть в своём ответе, что код взят из ответа на английском Stack Overflow и был модифицирован?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4897/23044)
- [What to do when plagiarism is discovered?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160071/what-to-do-when-plagiarism-is-discovered)
- [Users are calling me a plagiarist. What do I do?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160077/users-are-calling-me-a-plagiarist-what-do-i-do)
- [Как написать хороший ответ?](/help/how-to-answer)