# Сообщения со ссылками на спам–сайты будут блокироваться движком

Tags: поддержка, ссылки

На фоне роста популярности Stack Overflow на русском произошло крайне негативное событие для всего русскоязычного сообщества — начали появляться сайты, состоящие полностью из автоматически переведенных вопросов со Stack Overflow на английском. Проблема заключается в том, что содержимое таких сайтов невозможно понять: зачастую перевод — это просто набор слов, слабо связанных друг с другом.

Мы выступаем за знания без рамок одного языка, знания, которые нужны и важны людям, знания, которые поддерживаются сообществом. Спам–сайты — наш антипод. По представленному на спам–сайтах содержимому невозможно разобраться хоть в чем–то. Они не вносят никакой пользы, а только засоряют поисковую выдачу. Я убежден, что ссылаться на спам не стоит ни при каких обстоятельствах.

С настоящего момента, при попытке отправить вопрос или ответ со ссылкой на спам–сайт, участник будет получать ошибку со следующим пояснением:

> В вашем сообщении есть ссылка на спам–сайт, содержащий автоматически переведенный вопрос со Stack Overflow на английском. Спам–сайты засоряют русскоязычный Интернет. Пожалуйста, вставьте ссылку на исходный вопрос на Stack Overflow на английском или удалите её вовсе.

Известные мне спам–сайты на текущий момент, ссылки на которые мы блокируем:

- javahow.ru
- code.i-harness.com/ru
- ru.craftjs.com
- vpros.ru
- qaru.site
- ruphp.com
- stackoverrun.com
- programmerz.ru
- ubuntugeeks.com
- issue.life

Если вы столкнетесь с другими спам–сайтами, которые засоряют русскоязычное информационное пространство, пожалуйста, дайте знать. Как минимум, с нашего сайта мы выпилим вредителей и более к нам не пустим!

**Обновление**

Добавили проверку на публикацию ссылок на эти сайты в комментариях.

Comment: а как часто такое вообще наблюдается? (ссылка на спам-сайт)

Comment: Ещё можно предлагать сделать свой перевод (лишь бы не гуглтранслейтом) и оформить вопрос/ответ с ассоциацией.

Comment: Отличная идея! Только не слишком ли грубо называть их спам-сайтами?

Comment: @GreenDragon Не очень часто. Помню выпиливал qaru.site в прошлом месяце. Было с десяток ссылок.

Comment: @Qwertiy грубо? Определённо. Слишком? В ответ на нарушение лицензии SO ещё мягко :)

Comment: @D-side, так вроде ж решили, что они не нарушают лицензию, т. к. ставят ссылку на оригинал?

Comment: @Qwertiy об этом уже лучше знает Николас, но насколько мне известно, вся шумиха как раз из-за того, что ссылку не ставят.

Comment: @D-side, если бы не ставили, их бы уже потыкали чем-нибудь. А они ставят https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kZa9.png и лицензию не нарушают - у каждого ответа ссылка на источник, на профиль автора на enSO, а в футере указание лицензии https://i.stack.imgur.com/VT6cS.png

Comment: @Qwertiy круто! То есть, [с тех пор](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/22462?m=43482965#43482965) всё-таки приняли меры! Тогда да, можно поубавить градус :)

Comment: @D-side, когда я про них читал, там ссылки какие-то уже были, детальнее не проверял.

Comment: @Qwertiy Я им уже с полгода пописываю, а они время от времени что–нибудь да меняют так, что лицензии не удовлетворяют. Ко всему, изначально они взяли всю верстку SO (прям с названия css классов и структурой html, один в один). То есть они выдают себя за SO, но говорят, что это просто «совпадение». Это все лирика.

Comment: Содержимое этих сайтов — хлам, который засоряет Рунет. Одно дело авторский перевод человеком, другое дело то, что сделали авторы сайта. Поисковики это подхватывают и вместо ссылок на нормальные сайты, дают на них. А потом на встречах я слышу, что SOru — это сайт с переводами, а весь Рунет — помойка. Не надо нам таких спам–сайтов.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, так мож с ними не переписываться, а просто в суд подать?

Comment: @Qwertiy CC-BY-SA разрешает таким сайтам существовать, как я понимаю

Comment: Странно это. Бороться с сайтами, которые, по сути, ничего не нарушают.

Comment: @Suvitruf Проблема не в нарушении, а в качестве содержимого, на которое ссылаются со страниц нашего сайта. Содержимое этих сайтов не выдерживает никакой критики. Пожалуйста, посмотрите, например, на http://vpros.ru ([самый первый вопрос на их сайте](http://vpros.ru/52510-c-dlya-prokhozhdeniya-dopolnitelnykh-parametrov-v/)). Что скажите?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky ну, криво, да)

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: к слову, на ru.SO разрешено копирование с [en]SO без указания каких-либо ссылок: [Есть ли формальные требования как следует упомянуть в своём ответе, что код взят из ответа на английском Stack Overflow и был модифицирован?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4897/23044) Если запрещать ссылки на сайты с машинным переводом (которые кстати содержат нужные ссылки), то может и на ru.SO усилить требования к копированию?

Comment: @jfs Почему же? Как я понимаю, мы все–таки за правильную [атрибуцию](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4975/6). На мой взгляд, указывать автора при переиспользовании содержимого лучше даже в рамках одного сайта. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что именно вы имеете в виду под усилением?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: [резюме как сейчас в виде ответа](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4998/23044). Усиление: вместо *"на усмотрение автора"*  как сейчас, предлагаю как [на основном SO (из faq)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160071/137096): добавить правкой атрибуцию в ответ, оставить комментарий с ссылкой на Мету, где описано почему/как атрибуцию добавлять. Если автор не кооперирует, привлечь внимание модератора тревогой (чтобы правку с атрибуцией оставить)

Comment: @alexolut Вы не поверите, но ассоциации не работают: я приводил [примеры в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/43690796#43690796), когда ссылки на SOru нет, зато есть qaru. И... это система, а не случайность. Не знаю, чья это вина: поисковиков, которые спам подымают наверх, или сайты используют запрещённые приёмы индексации или so что-то неправильно делает. Я просто за сам факт говорю.

Comment: @AK На мой взгляд, необходимо детально исследовать данный вопрос в ближайшее время.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Стоит написать в Google и Yandex. Заранее нельзя сказать предпримут ли они что-то на этот счёт, но хотя бы узнают что такое есть, а если уже знают то поймут масштабность. Возможно через какое-то время они начнут такие сайты отлавливать алгоритмически или как-то по-другому и понижать им рейтинги. Про Google сказать не могу, но почти точно уверен что в Yandex задумаются и скорее всего что-то предпримут.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин я более чем уверен что в яндексе ничего предпринимать не будут.

Comment: В список: askdev.info; v-resheno.ru; Сложно понять откуда берут данные, скорее всего с SO.
Читать этот перевод невозможно.

Comment: В список: ohandroid.com

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky еще есть stackovernet.com (он же stackoverrun.com), [пример](https://ai.stackovernet.com/ru/q/324)

Comment: еще coredump.su, по другим языкам на [тостере](https://toster.ru/q/556616#answer_1306183)

Comment: Вот ещё один: dskims.com

Comment: @Alexshev92 Спасибо! Как я понимаю, этот сайта просто копирует SOen без обратных ссылок, но не переводит, верно?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, а, ну да. Они просто копируют enSO и ещё и ссылки не указывают. Я просто как увидел этот вырвиглазный дизайн забыл, что тут сайты-автопереводы собирают. Но в любом случае это спам-сайт.

Comment: Вот ещё один -- switch-case.ru -- похоже собирают автопереводы со всех сайтов сети stackexchange.

Comment: На qaru какую-то регистрацию начали пилить. Собираются становиться конкурентом stackoverflow с помощью базы вопросов stackoverflow?)

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky вот еще один сайт -  http://resolved-error.com. Но это не перевод, а вообще точная копия сайта...

Comment: ↑ Ну зачем делать кликабельные ссылки, поисковики их проиндексируют и поднимут в результатах поиска

Comment: Окей, вот некликабельные - issue . life и stackanswers . net

Comment: Просто бесят эти промты стека, в Гугле постоянно мелькают.  При вводе условной ошибки ссылка на qaru.site в выдаче бывает раньше самого стека.

Comment: @Axifive Пожалуйста, помогите в борьбе с сайтами машинного перевода: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8722/6

Comment: fliplinux.com похоже даже не даёт ссылок на оригинал на SO, как насчёт попробовать их засудить?)

Comment: Ещё один в копилку: web-answers.ru

Comment: sprosi.pro ещё.

Comment: @andreymal Спасибо!

Comment: Злостные нарушители, не дающие ссылок на оригинал: askvoprosy.com , quanz.ru , codengineering.ru , askdev.ru . Их как-то можно привлечь к ответу?

Comment: На rupython.com тоже не вижу ссылок на оригинал

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, еще один https://stackovergo.com/ru/

Comment: Нашёл ещё один такой сайтик: https://overcoder.net/ . Ссылок на оригинал нет.