# Какие ссылки на внешние ресурсы допустимы на сайте?

Tags: обсуждение, чат, ссылки

Уважаемые коллеги, меня интересует вопрос о ссылках, которые можно публиковать на сайте (как на основном, так и на Мете, и в чатах).

Я бы хотел, чтобы в ответе были зафиксированы *точные* и *окончательные* критерии, по которым можно было бы заранее узнать, имеет ли какая-либо ссылка право быть опубликованной на сайте. Очень хотелось бы, чтобы критерии были объективными, не зависящими от чьего-либо личного мнения.

Также, хотелось бы знать мотивацию, стоящую за этими ограничениями.

---

Прошу прощения за дополнение после данного уже ответа, но всё же меня волнует ещё один тесно связанный вопрос: если некоторые вопросы/ответы/сообщения чата *уже* содержат ссылки, не имеющие права на публикацию, что следует/можно с ними делать? В частности, не нужно ли их **все** удалить? Если не все, то какое конкретно подмножество?

---

Непосредственная причина для вопроса — удаление из нашего чата ссылки на чат на альтернативной платформе. Но, как мне кажется, общий ответ на этот вопрос был бы очень важен.

Comment: И неплохо бы с примерами: хабр, тостер, qaruподобные, сторонние чаты.

Answer (score 9):

Думаю, что допустимы ссылки на всё, что закон и правила сайта разрешают. Тостер, Квора, ответы Мейлру, Киберфорум — пожалуйста. Я не боюсь их конкуренции и уверен, что такие ссылки не повредят нашему сайту.
Но это только моё мнение. :) И к ссылкам применяются обычные правила:

- Ответ из одной ссылки удалят, потому что это не ответ, а не потому, что это ссылка куда-то там.
- Комментарий вроде «идите на сайт XYZ, он лучше чем этот» удалят, потому что это спам, а не потому что ссылка на тот сайт.
- Ссылку на поисковик или lmgtfy удалят, потому что она бесполезна и слегка так оскорбительна, а не потому что это другой сайт.
- Ссылку на свой сайт/блог/магазин в каждом посте удалят, потому что это навязчивая самореклама. Но можно дать такую ссылку один раз в своем профиле.

Суть: пишите полезные комментарии/ответы, дополняйте полезными ссылками по теме, и всё должно быть хорошо.

---

Есть один конкретный чат, на котором собираются участники, недовольные чем-то в этом сайте. Вообще, ребята, мне очень грустно, что вам пришлось такой чат открывать. Для меня это значит, что сначала между нами появились разногласия, а потом кто-то из вас перестал даже верить, что мы можем эти разногласия решить. Это в том числе моя ошибка — я мало заходил на сайт и не уследил за тем, чтобы вам было удобно и безопасно обсуждать проблемы прямо здесь.

Снова лично моё мнение: пожалуйста, обсуждайте проблемы хотя бы там. Будет здорово, если вы придёте потом с выводами сюда, на Мету. Обещаю ответить. В том чате не обещаю участвовать, потому что времени и сил хватит только на одно место. Ссылки на него уже есть у всех, кому это интересно. Опять же, лично я думаю, что никому эти ссылки не повредят.

Но если смотреть строго по правилам сайта — вы таким образом саботируете Мету. Логично, что наш сайт и чаты не предназначены для того, чтобы привлекать людей на другой сайт и чаты? Поэтому я понимаю, почему такие ссылки удаляются. Давайте лучше договоримся, как сделать, чтобы все могли безопасно обсуждать проблемы здесь, на Мете.

Как я уже сказал, я ошибся и недоработал, как модератор. Хочу исправить эту ошибку. Но мне нужна ваша помощь. Давайте искать решение вместе.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77030/discussion-on-answer-by-nick-volynkin------).

Comment: *«Ссылку на свой сайт/блог/магазин»*—можно явно упомянуть, что ссылки на конкретные статьи, которые имеют отношение к соответствующим вопросам/ответам, разрешены (если ссылка в ответе, то раскрытие своего авторства нужно добавить, если есть коммерческий интерес)

Answer (score 1):

Полностью поддерживаю [ответ](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7232/6) [@Nick Volynkin](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/181472/): каких–либо особенных ограничений на ссылки в публикуемых сообщениях на Stack Overflow нет. Ограничения исходят из правил сайта, лицензии сайта, на который ссылаются, действующего законодательства и здравого смысла.

Движок сайта не дает публиковать сообщения со ссылками на:

- Сайты вида lmgtfy. Такие ссылки в большинстве случаев не несут никакой ценности и [противоречат идеологии сайта](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2013/6).
- [Спам–сайты](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7104/), содержимое которых сгенерированно роботом и имеет нечитаемый для человека вид. О таких сайтах участники сообщают лично по мере их нахождения.

Я не знаю о других ограничениях на уровне движка (если что–то появится, обязательно обновлю ответ). Все остальное — пост модерация. Что именно будет удалено, а что — нет, зависит от того как конкретный участник понимает правила сообщества ([привилегии правки получают при достижении 2 000 баллов репутации](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit)).

На мой взгляд, в основном, все «выпиленные» правками ссылки, которые нельзя отнести к откровенному спаму (например, сайтам с запрещенным законом содержимым), как–либо связаны с [агрессивной] рекламой сторонних проектов, которые могут быть даже не связаны с [темой этого сайта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) (программированием). В справочном центре есть два раздела, в которых упоминается про спам и саморекламу: (1) [«Какое поведение ожидается от участников?»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior); (2) [«Как не быть спамером»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/promotion). Пожалуйста, прочитайте статьи. Для себя я отметил следующее:

- Создавайте хорошие и релевантные ответы и если часть из них (но не все) будут касаться вашей продукции или сайта, никто не будет возражать.
- Не используйте ссылки, кроме как на ресурсы, которые поддерживают то, что вы написали. (Имеется в виду, поддерживают сделанные вами технические рекомендации.)
- Если единственной причиной вашего присутствия здесь является продвижение вашей продукции или привлечение посетителей на ваш сайт, воздержитесь от ответов.
- Если вы хотите вести поддержку вашего продукта и сообщества, которое этот продукт использует на Stack Overflow, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь со статьей [«Можно ли осуществлять поддержку моего продукта на данном сайте?»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/product-support)

---

Дополнительно: конкретный вопрос рекламы личных чатов на Stack Exchange рассматривался ранее. [Примерный ответ](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/31774026#31774026)

> Когда модераторы или сотрудники компании пытаются разрешить проблему, они предполагают добрые намерения у всех участников «конфликта интересов». В то же время, у нас нет доступа к чатам за пределами Stack Exchange и мы не можем отслеживать взаимодействия участников вне нашей платформы. Поэтому, чтобы избежать ситуации, когда мы будем вынуждены плохо о ком–либо думать, пожалуйста:
>
> - В явной форме укажите, что ваш чат не является частью Stack Exchange.
> - Не рекламируйте ваш чат в «местах для всех»: основной сайт, Мета, основной чат сообщества.
> - Не допускайте присутствия в вашем чате людей, которых вы не знаете или которым не доверяете.
> - Избегайте принятия решений (подталкиванию к принятию решений) в вашем чате, которые каким–либо образом влияют на основной сайт, Мету или чаты, а также как–либо касаются участников нашего сообщества.

Comment: _если часть из них (но не все) будут касаться вашей продукции или сайта, никто не будет возражать_ - а если сайт используется в качестве поддержки? как было недавно с yandex-tank или как-то так? То есть как бы все вопросы/ответы будут связаны с продукцией

Comment: @Grundy Ребята поддержки из Яндекса отвечают на все вопросы по заданной метке (остальное по их личному желанию). Не думаю, что это выходит за рамки [условий поддержки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/product-support). На мой личный взгляд, то, что автор библиотеки отвечает на Stack Overflow на вопросы тех, кто ее использует, создает много пользы всем. Какой–то рекламы в этом вроде бы нет. Сравните «как правильно нанести маркер на карту Яндекса на андроид» и «как прикрутить карту к приложению на андроид».

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Мне хотелось бы, тем не менее, уточнить некоторые вещи в вашем ответе. Во-первых, это «здравый смысл». Это очень широкое понятие, которое может трактоваться разными участниками по-разному. (Примеры этого могу привести.) Таким образом, это понятие **не является объективным**. Если вы говорите, что «здравый смысл» тоже является валидным источником запрещения каких-либо ссылок, этим самым, как я понимаю, декларируется, что субъективное мнение удаляющего является достаточным основанием для удаления. Прошу подтвердить или опровергнуть это.

Comment: Далее, вы говорите: «Что именно будет удалено, а что — нет, зависит от того как конкретный участник понимает правила сообщества». Это, очевидно, обходит вопрос о том, является ли такое удаление _хорошей правкой_ или _вандализмом_. Я в вопросе просил _точные_, _окончательные_ и _объективные_ критерии того, уместна ли ссылка на сайте, а личное понимание каждым конкретным участником таковым, очевидно, не является ни в какой мере.

Comment: Далее, «агрессивность» также является, очевидно, субъективным понятием. Хороший недавний пример — ссылка на `zulipchat` в чате мной не рассматривалась ни как агрессивная, ни как реклама, а удалена была, насколько я понимаю, именно как агрессивная реклама. Следовательно, у нас снова нету объективного критерия.

Comment: Далее, отдельный пункт — ссылки в чате. Совершенно очевидно, что там нет ссылок на «только программирование». Соответственно, откуда вдруг следует отдельное правило, по которому нельзя публиковать ссылки на сторонние чаты, мне неясно. Если это отдельное правило, будьте добры, сформируйте его максимально точно. Если это правило как-то следует из того текста, который над чертой, укажите, пожалуйста, как именно. Если отдельного правила нет, и из остальных правил это не следует, я требую удаления этого ограничения.

Comment: @VladD Пожалуйста, обратите внимание, это не запрет, а пост модерация, которая в подавляющем большинстве случаев осуществляется участниками сообщества. Пост модерация осуществляется либо несколькими участниками (правка + подтверждение или несколько голосов), либо проверенным участником, чей здравый смысл не вызывает вопросов. Уверен, вы понимаете, что написать четкий список сайтов, ссылки на которые следует удалить при модерировании невозможно, так как в мире слишком много неоднозначных сайтов.

Comment: На Stack Overflow есть много субъективных инструментов модерации, например, голоса за и против вопросов. Это не вызывает проблем до тех пор, пока кто–то не захочет использовать систему не по назначению.

Comment: *Я в вопросе просил точные, окончательные и объективные критерии* — Пожалуйста, учтите, сайт модерирует сообщество. Главный критерий — правила и миссия сайта. Если кто–либо будет не согласен с каким–то конкретным случаем модерации и задаст на Мете вопрос с аргументированным ответом, мы вместе рассмотрим его и уточним правила (наш общий «здравый смысл»).

Comment: @VladD Поясните, пожалуйста, ваш последний комментарий. Я его не понял.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: Я не вижу особой разницы между запретом, и разрешением удалять при пост-модерации (здесь мы говорим не о чате, а об основном сайте, верно?). В любом случае, в этом случае, если я правильно понимаю, критерием является здравый смысл «проверенного участника». В том, что здравый смысл проверенного участника не вызывает вопросов, я лично сомневаюсь, хотя бы потому, что из нас двоих мнения о законности ссылок расходятся. Следовательно, возможна ситуация, когда «здравый смысл» не срабатывает. Какое правило применяется в этом случае?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: Обратите внимание, что голоса являются почти строго описанными правилами: участник имеет право голосовать, как он хочет, за исключением серийного голосования (ну и упомянутого некоторое время назад PashaPash и неподтверждённого справкой запрета «голосовать как мне хочется»). Удаление же и редактирование чужих текстов таким чётким и простым регламентом не обладают.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: Извините, но лозунг о том, что сайт модерируется сообществом, лишь частично верен. Комментарии удаляются администрацией **без согласования с сообществом** и против его (сообщества) воли. Поэтому я настаиваю на точных и честных критериях. Правила сайта чересчур обширны, и я просил в вопросе точную формулировку, а не отсыл читать правила. Я читал правила, не нашёл там ответа на свой вопрос.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: По поводу конкретного случая модерации, насколько мне помнится (поправьте меня, если это не так), многократно озвучивались призывы не выносить конкретные имена и конкретные поступки на Мету. В данном случае я руководствуюсь именно этими призывами, и спрашиваю о точных правилах, а не о конкретном удалении ссылки, о котором тоже упомянуто в вопросе.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: По поводу моего последнего комментария 14.05: ваш ответ очевидным образом не относится к ссылкам в чате. Например, в чате есть **много** ссылок на сайты и темы, не относящиеся прямо к программированию, следовательно процитированное вами правило «Не используйте ссылки, кроме как на ресурсы, которые поддерживают то, что вы написали», самоочевидно, к нему не относится. Следовательно, обосновать запрет публикации ссылки на альтернативный чат этим правилом не удастся.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: Далее, поскольку правила, которые вы привели, как мы только что выяснили, не относятся к чату, то я бы ожидал включения такого **полного** набора правил в ответ. В частности, я хотел бы видеть правило, по которому ссылки на альтернативный чат не разрешены. (Но, разумеется, не только это правило, а полный набор правил.)

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: То, что вопрос альтернативных чатов рассматривался на SE, не отменяет вопроса о конкретном зафиксированном правиле насчёт чатов. Хотел бы в этой связи ещё отметить пассаж о том, будто бы участники SO должны вести себя так, чтобы не произошло событие «**мы** будем вынуждены плохо о ком–либо думать». Этот пассаж крайне возмутителен, и я надеюсь, вы самостоятельно понимаете, почему.

Comment: @VladD _разницы между запретом, и разрешением удалять_ — разница, на мой взгляд, колоссальная: одно дело спустить «сверху» «нельзя!», другое — когда сами участники, незнакомые друг с другом индивиды, публично удаляют ссылки на свое усмотрения, страх и риск исходя из понимания правил.

Comment: *когда «здравый смысл» не срабатывает. Какое правило применяется в этом случае?* — выносить вопрос на Мету, аргументируя свой выбор в одном из ответов. Если «здравый смысл» расходится, вероятно, у одной из сторон есть больше информации или, наоборот, какое–то недопонимание. Тому пример, моя правка комментариев, которая  пришлась не по нраву авторам этих комментариев (в этом случае я не обладал всем полнотой картины и допустил некоторую «психологическую» ошибку). Вопрос на Мете добавил недостающий у меня информации.

Comment: *Комментарии удаляются администрацией без согласования с сообществом и против его (сообщества) воли.* — по хорошему, комментарии должны удаляться модераторами, которых выбрало сообщество. Если управляющий вынужден вмешиваться и удалять их самостоятельно, значит модераторов либо мало (не получается охватить все), либо они не понимают правила, либо выбор был неверен (когда они понимают правила, но делают по–своему в обход правилам сообщества). Это проблема. Будем ее решать.

Comment: Так или иначе, комментарии удаляются за нарушение правил сообщества и только за них. Управляющий всегда придерживается нейтралитета, строго придерживаясь правилам. Четких правил «вот это слово нельзя писать» не будет по понятным всем причинам. Вместо этого мы руководствуемся принципами, например, принципом дружелюбия. Принципы легче понять, быстрее запомнить, проще уточнить и дополнить, а модерация становится понятнее и приятнее.

Comment: *спрашиваю о точных правилах* — мысль в том, чтобы уточнять конкретные вопросы, без привязки к участнику. Ваша просьба  «описать все на свете» — совсем о другом. Она скорее является дополнением (в терминах теории множеств), чем допустимым подмножеством: обычно мы рассматриваем один конкретный случай, одно конкретное правило, а не всеобъемлющие вопросы, которые описаны в справке. На конкретный вопрос «что запрещено на уровне движка» есть конкретный ответ: «спам сайты» (список), lmgtfy и его аналоги.

Comment: *обосновать запрет публикации ссылки на альтернативный чат этим правилом не удастся* — про чат–сервисы есть отдельная секция. *мы* — относится ко всем людям, принимающим участие в модерировании (управляющим, модераторам, обычным участникам). Спам никто не любит.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: Тем не менее, несмотря на эту разницу, есть достаточно большая общая часть: если правила разрешают публиковать ссылку не ресурс Х, то любое удаление этой ссылки может быть оспорено. Если правил нет, то, выходит, «кто первый удалил, тот и прав»?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: «если здравый смысл не срабатывает, выносить на Мету» — хорошо, почему бы вам не дописать это в ответ? Но при этом непонятно, что делать человеку, который на Мете забанен.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: «по хорошему, комментарии должны удаляться модераторами» — тут начали за здравие, a konchili za upokoj. Вы говорите «Если управляющий вынужден вмешиваться и удалять их самостоятельно, значит модераторов либо мало (не получается охватить все), либо они не понимают правила, либо выбор был неверен». Я правильно понимаю, что это значит, что модератор должен следовать правилам? Тогда возвращаемся к вопросу: **перечислите правила**! Потому что мне, извините, нет разницы, удалит ссылку по правилам модератор или администрация.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky:  ... Если ссылка удаляется по правилам, эти правила должны быть доступны. И именно об этой самой доступности правил и мой вопрос.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: «Так или иначе, комментарии удаляются за нарушение правил сообщества и только за них» — списка этих правил я пока так и не увидел. «Четких правил «вот это слово нельзя писать» не будет по понятным всем причинам.» — мне эти причины непонятны. Нельзя ли их огласить? Во избежание злоупотреблений. Вот например, по какому принципу удалена ссылка на посторонний чат? Где в правилах это запрещено? Мне кажется, вы уходите от конкретного ответа на конкретный вопрос.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: «Ваша просьба «описать все на свете» — совсем о другом». Возможно. Я хочу точно и **наперёд** знать, какую ссылку я могу опубликовать с тем, чтобы её **не удалили**.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: «про чат–сервисы есть отдельная секция» — простите, а где она есть?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: «мы — относится ко всем людям, принимающим участие в модерировании (управляющим, модераторам, обычным участникам)» + «чтобы избежать ситуации, когда мы будем вынуждены плохо о ком–либо думать». Сама идея о том, что кто-либо из участников должен себя вести так, чтобы не дай бог администрация, модераторы или ещё кто-то плохо не подумал, кажется мне возмутительной. Никто из перечисленных людей не является моими родителями, и не смеют предписывать мне, как себя вести.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: Само предложение вводить ограничения в моей деятельности вне сайта, чтобы у кого-то из участников сайта или администрации не возникло каких-либо подозрений, кажется мне дерзостью, переходящей всякие границы. Не слишком ли много сайт на себя берёт?

Comment: @VladD *ограничения в моей деятельности вне сайта* — это, конечно же, не так. Мысль в том, что чтобы не ввест в заблуждение других, мы просим не размещать ссылки на сторонние платформы (четкое описание в ответе) в основных публичных местах, то есть мы заботимся о наших участниках на нашем сайте. Ограничения наложены на размещаемые на этом сайте ссылки.

Comment: *который на Мете забанен*  — блокировка на сайте, в общем случае, дело очень серьезное. Блокировка редко присходит без предупреждения. Если участник получил блокировку, он отлично понимал о том, какое поведение нарушает правила, о том, что в случае продолжения, он будет заблокирован, а при получении предупреждения, он решил не выносить вопрос на Мету, а продолжил делать то, что делал — нарушать правила. В реальной жизни, подавляющее большенство участников имеет возможность вынести вопрос на Мету до блокировки, но после того, как им подсказали, что, вероятно, их поведение нарушает правила сайта

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: «чтобы не ввест в заблуждение других, мы просим не размещать ссылки на сторонние платформы [...] то есть мы заботимся о наших участниках на нашем сайте» Извините, это не выглядит адекватным. То есть вы отказываете участникам в здравом смысле и возможности самим, без вашего надзора и контроля решить, что имн следует читать, а что нет? **В чём конкретно выражается «забота»?** Поскольку смысла в «заботе» такого рода о взрослых людях я не вижу, мне кажется, что вы пытаетесь придумать оправдание для цензуры неугодных администрации ссылок.

Comment: @VladD *что имн следует читать, а что нет*  — это не так. На мой взгляд, прямая аналогия — отзыв лицензии ЦБ у сомнительных банков. Вы можете давать ваши деньги кому угодно, сколько угодно, хоть соседу Василию, но ваш вклад застрахован только в тех банках, которые ЦБ считает надежными. Правда, мы скорее ведем список плохих «банков» (например, спам–сайты), а не хороших.

Answer (score -5):

Если я правильно понимаю, то допустимыми являются только ссылки на страницы, принадлежащие сообществу stackexchange. Остальные являются *нежелательными*.

Причина одна - система гарантирует жизнеспособность таких ссылок вечно. В то время как страницы на других ресурсах могут удаляться или переезжать на новые адреса и тогда ссылка окажется ведущей в никуда.

Comment: То есть, ссылку на MSDN давать нельзя? (Минус не мой)

Comment: @VladD Так MS постоянно же двигает алгоритм адресации своих страниц. Ты ссылку оставил, а через пару лет она уже и не рабочая. Где-то мне попадалось, что корректно оставлять ссылку, если основная часть контента этой ссылки вставлена в сам ответ/комментарий

Comment: То есть таки нельзя? Окей. Вы не против, если я уточню вопрос?

Comment: Ключевое слово "нежелательными". Это рекомендация, не более.

Comment: Это совершенно точно неправда. В ответах ссылки на сторонние ресурсы, подкрепляющие или дополняющие сказанное, как раз приветствуются.

Comment: @D-side ну, не совсем. Т.к. внешние ссылки могут протухнуть.

Comment: @Suvitruf могут, поэтому ответы не должны на них **основываться** (link-only). Но дополнения обычно только в плюс.

Comment: @D-side вот ещё тред по теме https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7229/15479 если ссылка на свой сайт, то могут посчитать за спам O:

Comment: @Suvitruf могут, об этом есть в справке, снизу: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior

Comment: @D-side угу. Но мой вопрос про чат был, правда)

Comment: "Причина одна - система гарантирует жизнеспособность таких ссылок вечно." - а вот и нет, не гарантирует. Автор вопроса на SE может удалить его, ссылка протухнет, и система ничего с этим не сделает. Разве что есть механизм защиты от удаления вопросов, если на них есть ссылка, но я про такой не слышал (и даже не представляю, как такое возможно).

Comment: То есть переводы вопросов-ответов с En.SO в топку (иначе будет нарушение лицензии)? И ссылки на спецификации тоже в топку?