# Корректировка правил о спаме в отношении чата

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, чат, правила

Уже есть [важное обсуждение по поводу того, какие ссылки допустимы](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7224/15479). Но в данном вопросе хотел бы затронуть тему неоднозначности правил в плане чата.

**Контекст**: была проблема с некоторыми сообщениями в [SVG чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70612/svg-chat). Сообщение были удалены, ссылаясь на правила [о рекламе своих ресурсов в ответах/вопросах](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/promotion).

Все, я думаю, согласятся, что спам - это плохо. Но вопрос сейчас о том, относится ли этот пункт правил к чату. К сожалению, я вынужден скопировать [конкретное сообщение](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/44355607#44355607) о вынесенном решении:

> Там не сказано явно, но это не отменяет сути. Не волнуйтесь, я
>   консультировался с коллегами в компании. Если вы считаете данное
>   решение не обоснованным, пожалуйста, воспользуйтесь формой обратной
>   связи.

Я знаю о решении. Те, кто в чате, знают. А другие люди могут наступить на те же грабли.

За сим предлагаю доработать эту страницу правил и внести туда явно пункты касательно чата, чтобы не было неоднозначности.

Comment: А разве в чате нет своих правил? Почему правила поведения в чате должны регламентироваться правилами ruSO?

Comment: @vp_arth в том примере, что я привёл, санкции были применены именно на основании правил сайта.

Comment: @vp_arth: [согласно Tim Post♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309645/137096) если чат нарушает [CoC](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) (флаги не выставляются, или хуже поощряется поведение, нарушающее CoC, или людей, которые указывают на это кикают из чата), то такой чат будет закрыт  (я только один пример знаю, когда это произошло) и никакие ссылки на локальную культуру не спасут.

Comment: @Suvitruf: это не ответ на ваш вопрос, а иллюстрация для вопроса vp_auth: *"а разве в чате нет своих правил"* -- пример говорит, что правила одни на всех (не важно какой сайт, чат, не чат).

Comment: Оффтопик [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77063/discussion-on-question-by-suvitruf-------).

Comment: общее замечание: стоит обратить внимание на фразу выделенную жирным шрифтом: [*"And that gets us to the hard part. It's terribly difficult and ineffective to write a list of things you can or can't say in chat."*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309645/137096)

Comment: @jfs другие сервисы как-то справляются.