# Международные Stack Overflow: неограниченно, вовремя, развёрнуто на родном языке

Tags: обсуждение, локализация

Это перевод вопроса с MSE: [International Stack Overflows: Unlimited, On Time, and Comprehensive in your native language](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/316522/339911)

> #### TL;DR
>
> Мне часто задают вопрос «В чем миссия международных сайтов? Какие проблемы они разрешают?». Мой ответ «Этот как Stack Overflow на английском, только на другом языке» делает международные сайты ещё более загадочными. Мы подумали, что было бы здорово развеять туман таинственности, добавив страницу–манифест в справочный центр. Пожалуйста, обратите внимание на страницу **[ru.stackoverflow.com/help/manifesto](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/manifesto)**. Расскажите нам, что вы думаете о ней! Страница доступна для редактирования модераторам, мы будем признательны за перевод.

Позвольте поделится мыслями позади миссия. Для начала, пожалуйста, задумайтесь в чем разница между разработчиком, для которого английский язык родной, и тем, для кого английский не является таковым? Как это различие влияет на их жизни?

[image]

<sub>(Я нашёл эту картинку в [Google Images](https://www.timeshighereducation.com/sites/default/files/styles/the_breaking_news_image_style/public/nick-shepherd-illustration-040216.jpg).)</sub>
<sub>Этой иллюстрацией я хочу показать, что опыт перехода от точки А к точке В в значительной степени зависит от окружения, путь одной длины для одинаковых людей может сильно различаться.</sub>

#### Проблема неанглоязычных разработчиков: мало, поздно, не понятно

Если вы попробуете найти ответ на вопрос по программированию на языке, отличном от английского, то в основном в результатах поиска будут ссылки на перегруженные информацией phpBB форумы, ответы, разбросанные по комментариям в блогах или цепочкам почтовых рассылок и т.п. Единственный качественный источник знаний на выбранном языке по-прежнему книги. Как будто мы вернулись 2007: крайне сложно найти какое–либо решение нетривиальной технической проблемы.

Другими словами, сегодня существует огромная асимметрия в информации, доступной на разных языках. Разработчики во всем мире, которые не говорят по-английски, имеют *меньше* доступной информации, она появляется *с задержкой*, а часть важных нюансов может *потеряться* при переводе.

Повлиял ли Stack Overflow на английском на эту ситуацию? Да, безусловно! В течение последних нескольких лет мы наблюдаем [рассвет сайтов, все содержимое которых — робо–переводы со Stack Overflow на английском](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7104/6). Можно только мечтать, чтобы это был качественный машинный перевод с последующей правкой человеком. В действительности же все содержимое подобных сайтов — это тонна спамо-подобных текстов, смысл большей части которых непонятен человеку. Существует дюжина таких сайтов с несколькими миллионами сгенерированных страниц на каждом из них. Это то, что мы, неанглоязычные разработчики, видим в результатах поиска каждый день... Это не шутка.

Такая ситуация создаёт огромное неравенство между разработчиками, чей основной язык английский, и остальными. Для большой части населения мира программирование все еще что–то магическое, порог вхождения в отрасль всё ещё высок, изучение программирования остается очень сложным и дорогостоящим занятием.

Сегодняшняя индустрия информационных технологий не рассчитана для людей вне англоговорящего мира. Вместе мы изменим этот тренд!

#### Цель: развернутый ответ на любой вопрос по программированию на родном языке

Сегодня люди со схожими возможностями и одинаковым желанием изучать программирование, начав свой путь в одно и то же время, через несколько лет могут иметь большую разницу в знаниях и опыте работы из-за диспропорции информации на родном языке и того, насколько она доступна.

Миссия и цель международных Stack Overflow — создать мир, где каждый имеет равные возможности добиться успеха в программировании, независимо от того, какой язык для него родной.

#### Подход Stack Overflow: неограниченно, вовремя, развернуто

Мы все начинаем с одного — неудержимого стремления стать разработчиком. Различие лишь в том, что кто–то имеет *достаточно* *исчерпывающих* материалов *когда это необходимо* на своем родном языке, а кто—то — нет. Те, у кого нет доступа ко всем нужным знаниям, должны тратить миллион триллионов дополнительного времени на перевод материалов и многократное перечитывание их, с целью уточнения всех нюансов изучаемых технологий. Если мы хотим повысить нашу производительность, с этим надо что–то делать.

Мы убеждены, что фундамент желаемых изменений — это хорошо структурированная библиотека развернутых ответов на все вопросы по программированию, созданная сообществом взаимной помощи.

#### Stack Overflow говорит на многих языках

Stack Overflow — это мы, разработчики всего мира, которые хотят помогать другим, которые ищут ответы по программированию в интернете, вне зависимости от того, какой язык мы предпочитаем как для программирования, так и для обмена знаниями с коллегами.

Без вас, мудрость сообщества не будет цельной! Пожалуйста, примите участие в жизни международных сообществ: задавайте вопросы, отвечайте на вопросы других участников. Расскажите вашим друзьям зачем нужны международные Stack Overflow. Сообщества растут только благодаря ваши рекомендациям!

Comment: За картинку и первый абзац после неё даже обидно стало.

Comment: Хотя и дальше не лучше. Лично мне этот текст противен.

Comment: @ixSci: от чего же?

Comment: @Kir_Antipov от того, что некоторые мыслями остались вначале 2000-х и думают, что в рунете ничего нет.

Comment: @Suvitruf: сие, конечно, да. Однако в любом случае на русском материала в разы меньше, чем на английском. К примеру, информацию по `VSIX` я нахожу лишь на английском ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ Да и стоит упомянуть, что речь тут не только про ruSO, но и про всякие японско-мексиканские ответвления) Тут уж Вы, думаю, не будете спорить, что существуют комьюнити, где с литературой и правда плачевно)

Comment: Пропагандистская листовка какая-то. Вопроса здесь нет, ничего нового читатель из этого текста не извлечет. Нужна ли метка «важное»?

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, оттого, что это выглядит как будто у нас тут была выжженная земля, по которой бегали папуасы, пока не пришли белые англоязычные люди с великим ресурсом Stack Overflow. После чего на папуасов начали снисходить знания. Особенно позорно это смотрится в оригинале, т.к. вообще непонятно, зачем англоязычной аудитории нужен этот унизительный текст.

Comment: @ixSci может стоит свою позицию выразить в форме ответа? Если, конечно, на MSE не собираетесь писать под оригиналом.

Comment: @ixSci: как-то больно негативно многие воспринимают данный текст. Не забывайте, что он написан не только для ruSO, а для усреднённого международного SO. И высказываются, на мой взгляд, в данном посте совсем иные тезисы, нежели поняли Вы

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, мне безразличны другие ресурсы. Он написан русским менеджером сообщества, с примерами из рунета, т.к. очевидно, что опыта с портунетом и япононетом у него нет. Поэтому воспринимать его как нечто усреднённое я тоже не собираюсь.

Comment: @ixSci: однако факт есть факт - Николас ныне КМ не только для ruSO. И как всегда он пишет не совсем то, что хотел бы иметь в виду. Основной посыл - человеку куда легче обжиться и накапливать знания в среде родного языка, так что для сего и создаются международные комьюнити. Согласен, что часть текста под первым заголовком выглядит... кхм... странно, как будто мы бездомные, шарящиеся по интернет-помойкам в поисках необходимой информации. Но, зная стиль выражения Николаса, он совсем не то хотел сказать ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @ixSci: я не веду к тому, что текст не надо править. Я просто о том, что не стоит **за это** сильно обижаться на КМ)

Comment: @alexolut, ответил на MSE

Comment: @ixSci без толку писать там, где люди снисходительно относятся к не en говорящим.

Comment: @Suvitruf мне кажется, что писать в принципе без толку. Я просто решил выразить своё мнение и посмотреть на результат. Толку от этого нет никакого, равно как и от самого поста Николая на MSE. Я вообще не понимаю, что он там делает и для кого написан.

Comment: @ixSci а, это да. Весь этот манифест - просто огрызок от тура. Видимо, для галочки просто.

Comment: @ixSci  Привет! Спасибо за отзыв. Пожалуйста, перечитайте публикацию на русском языке. Предыдущий вариант был очень сильно искажен.

Comment: @ixSci Публикация на MSE на английском идет в рамках [процесса ведения инициатив международных сайтов](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315311/274323). В двух словах, мы используем MSE (1) потому что это эффективнее (я не знаю всех языков, а переводы будут занимать столько времени, что можно даже не начинать), (2) чтобы добиться большей публичности происходящего в международных сообществах (мы теперь видим инициативы в других сообществах).

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, тогда будьте, добры, пожалуйста, пишите более нейтральные посты. Мне действительно обидно читать подобные вещи. Это очень по-русски писать как у нас всё плохо, и как хорошо у них там. Да, Вы так прямо не пишите, но именно так это воспринимается, по крайней мере мной. И вдвойне обидно за то, что это подано в таком свете, что SO является чем-то важным. Т.е. до него как будто мы жили в пелене, а сейчас всё изменилось. Но это не так. Дело в людях и только в них, SO это или phpBB — не важно.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, что касается непосредственно цели поста на MSE. Там в самом начале: _“What is the mission of our International Sites? What problems do they solve?” The answer, “They are just like Stack Overflow in English, only in a different language”_ Разве этого не достаточно, кому-то действительно нужно другое обоснование? Но ведь другого обоснования нет и быть не может!

Comment: @ixSci Я, конечно же, никого не хотел обидеть. SO, на мой взгляд, действительно вносит немалый вклад в развитие индустрии: знаний становится больше, они бесплатные из за чего сильно ускоряется процесс разработки. То, что раньше можно было реализовать за неделю, делается за пару часов. Это возможно потому, что информация структурирована хорошо, и она, эта информация, *есть*.

Comment: @ixSci В природе нет места пустоте. Когда–то, еще до появления SO, был ExpertsExchange, который предлагал доступ к знаниям сообщества созданным бесплатно, за деньги. Если бы SO не было, был бы ExpertsExchange и доступ по подписке. Сегодня у международных сообществ свои проблемы — автогенераторы. По ним не научиться ничему. Я очень хочу общими силами решить эту проблему. Пожалуйста, заметьте, эта наша проблема и решить ее можем только мы, англоговорящие тут вообще ни при чем. Либо мы наполним Рунет настоящими человеческими знаниями, либо он будет сгенерирован.

Comment: @ixSci Пожалуйста, подскажите, что именно в тексте вам кажется обидным?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky скорость роста базы на английском языке всё равно не позволит ruSO обойти в поиске те же самые qa.ru. Тут надо, либо поисковики чтобы такие сайты блокировали, либо лицензию менять, чтобы нельзя было копировать сообщения.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Картинка оскорбляет и первый абзац после неё(особенно её связка ). **" Как всегда бедный и тупой Ваня идет своим путём , Пока Джим, Тарас, Шямолан, идут по прекрасному мощёному хичвею"** .

Comment: @alexolut если поменять лицензию - то нельзя будет копировать и решения с SO себе в код :)

Comment: @ixSci Выжженной земли не было. но "мало, поздно, непонятно" действительно есть. Вот только масштаб проблемы тяжело оценить опытному разработчику с нормальным уровнем английского. Я, например, редко нахожу решения именно на русском - просто потому, что я ищу их сразу на английском. Вы, я уверен, тоже. Но огромное количество людей, особенно начинающего уровня, просто изолированы от англоязычных ресурсов.

Comment: А когда появятся версии SO, скажем, на киргизском, белорусском и других языках? Ведь многие не знают не только английский, но и русский...

Comment: @PashaPash можно подумать, что сейчас копируют исключительно вместе со ссылками на пост и профиль автора :)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov пока НИКОГДА. Добавление новых языков заморожено. Но может быть что-то с новым международным КМ сдвинется с мёртвой точки.

Comment: @alexolut я оставляю у себя в коде комменты-ссылки. на всякий случай :)

Comment: @PashaPash ну вот, даже ромбоносные модераторы не придерживаются полного перечня требований :) Что же говорить об обычных смертных, не имеющих аккаунта.

Comment: @alexolut я обязательно расставлю attribution по коду, как только решим отдавать наш древний проект в опенсорс :)

Comment: @PashaPash, это правда, сейчас я ищу на английском. Более того, если у меня будет вопрос по C++ я его задам на enSO, а не здесь. Но учился я на русском. С русскими книжками и русским форумами (в большей степени винград). У меня не было проблем с обучением, и я не был сметён количеством открывшийся информации, после того, как выучил английский на нормально уровне. Да у нас чего-то нет, это правда. Но драматизировать, думаю, не стоит. К тому же, если чего-то нет, то руСО тут как поможет? Всё ведь от людей зависит. Если не хотят сложные вещи описывать на русском, так и не будут.

Comment: @ixSci проблема не столько в наличи (есть. меньше, но есть), сколько в отставании по времени. Русскоязычные новички учатся по ресурсам вроде metanit и по старым туториалам. Книги опаздывают на несколько лет. Простой пример - топовая книга про .NET, [CLR via C# (Неувядающая классика)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416584/). Английское 4-е издание - 2013-й год. Русский перевод - 2016-й. За эти три года вышло 3 major версии языка, а платформа уехала куда-то в линукс и опенсорс. Да, отвечают люди, но ruSO - это хороший способ собрать отвечающих вместе за счет известности бренда.

Comment: @PashaPash, тем не менее Албахари C# 7.0 есть на русском, как и отличная книга Йосуттиса по C++, которая вышла под занавес 2017 на английском. Отставание есть, тут никуда не деться — не мы «заказываем музыку». Насчёт бренда согласен.

Comment: Соглашусь, что в рунете информация запаздывает. Примеры: интересовался Powershell Empire, на русском одна(уже две) статья, на английском - много. Или Хабр. Наверное почти треть статей - переводы. Недавно вышла интересная статья, это был перевод en-статьи февраля 2018. Так что да, надо что делать.