# Кто-то скопировал сайт ru.StackOverflow?

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка

Кто-то скопировал сайт ru.StackOverflow? Сегодня увидел вот такое - `http://resolved-error.com/s__ru/users/6953/spoilt`

Comment: похоже на просто прокси

Comment: Лучше на мете спросите

Comment: @StrangerintheQ не просто прокси. Там в коде аналитика гугловская левая подключена.

Comment: Надо добавлять сюда: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7104/218063

Comment: @АндрейNOP написал в ту тему также

Comment: Энциклонги возвращаются!

Comment: Поднял вопрос в чате: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49326074#49326074

Comment: есть ещё некий qaru.info, например [вот](http://qaru.site/questions/26978/best-practice-to-return-errors-in-aspnet-web-api)