# Скопирован аккаунт

Tags: обсуждение, авторские-права

#### Описание

Наткнулся на сайт, где существует [аккаунт с моим никнеймом](https://prog-help.ru/author/eccs0103/), где существуют ещё [**все** вопросы которые я задал на обычном сайте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/324730/eccs0103?tab=questions&sort=newest). На данный момент при просмотре видно только вопросы начиная с 11.10.2022,

[image]

но я не уверен, что вопросы до этого отсутствуют. Конечно сайт указывает везде источники на вопросы,

[image]

но мне не нравится то, что где-то может существовать копия моего аккаунта.

---

Как я уже ранее сказал, существует пользователь с моим никнеймом, который публикует мои вопросы, но я не в курсе об этом и не имею доступ к этому аккаунту.

#### Вопрос

Является ли этот сайт сотрудником или кем то ещё со ruSO? Допустима ли копия аккаунта в других сайтах? Что я могу на данный момент с этим делать?

Comment: Таких сайтов, которые копируют данные со стековерфлоу, множество. Странно, что вы только что об этом узнали.

Comment: Сделать с этим ничего нельзя. Это гнилая политика администрации stackoverflow, которая специально ничего не предпринимает против таких сайтов. Таким образом уничтожаются другие _нормальные_ форумы и сайты вопросов-ответов.

Comment: Не переживайте. Информация должна быть свободной. Сказав что-либо в инернете вы уже не можете ограничить доступ к этому

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov до этого я множество сайтов встретил на котором вопросы из SO, но полную копию аккаунта, ещё и с никнеймом, ещё и моего первый раз.

Comment: @eccs0103, [давно](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7104/186999) такого не было

Comment: @Grundy сайт этот намного интереснее чем я думал. Там и [ваш](https://prog-help.ru/author/Grundy/), и вопросы других участников ([Harry](https://prog-help.ru/author/Harry/), [avp](https://prog-help.ru/author/avp/), [andreymal](https://prog-help.ru/author/andreymal/), [Nofate](https://prog-help.ru/author/Nofate/), [maestro](https://prog-help.ru/author/maestro/)) есть, но частично, в отличие от моего.

Comment: скорее всего просто `api` сайта SO используют, чтобы наполнить свой сайт ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Лицензия Creative Commons позволяет такое делать