# Наши ассоциации вопросов в текущем виде нарушают лицензию CC BY-SA

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, ассоциация-вопросов, лицензирование

Как многие знают, у нас есть механизм [ассоциаций вопросов](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4409/15479) ([ещё](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4120/15479) по теме и [ещё](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4857/15479)).

Недавно на оригинальном SO появился пост о том, что [такие переводы могут нарушать лицензию](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394396/1991579).

Там при обсуждении [отметили](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/394401/1991579), если не указана ссылка на оригинал, то это нарушает [лицензию](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/):

> Attribution — You must give appropriate credit, provide a link to the license, and indicate if changes were made. You may do so in any reasonable manner, but not in any way that suggests the licensor endorses you or your use.

Обсуждения на MSE по теме:

- [Is it OK to translate and repost Stack Overflow questions/answers in different language?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/218048/260198).
- [Is it OK to crosspost Stack Overflow questions, now that the Portuguese SO is open?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/218055/260198).

В общем-то, у нас в справке есть [статья про это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/translate-from-english). И там упоминается необходимость указания источника:

> [Соблюдайте лицензию](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4975/15479). Не забывайте отблагодарить авторов вопроса и ответов обратной ссылкой на сообщение-источник на английском языке.

Разумнее всего во все подобные вопросы/ответы всегда добавлять ссылки на оригинальные сообщение. Тоже самое касается и всех старых сообщений-ассоциаций.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Небольшой итог по [обсуждению этого вопроса в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/53807508#53807508). По теме:

- [Статья в справке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/translate-from-english).
- [По поводу лицензии](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4975/15479).

**TL;DR:** нужно соблюдать лицензию. Для этого в сообщении-переводе (и/или ассоциации) нужно указывать ссылку на источники и на авторов.

Один из предложенных вариантов оформления (для случая с переводом):

```
<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [«заголовок вопроса»](ссылка на вопрос) от участника  [@имя автора](ссылка на профиль).</sub>
```

---

Выглядеть будет так (на примере [одного моего вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/871121/15479)):

<sub>При формировании ответа использовался [ответ на вопрос «What is null in Java?»](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2707333/1991579) от участника [@polygenelubricants](https://stackoverflow.com/users/276101/polygenelubricants).</sub>

---

- Для правильной работы ассоциаций всё также необходимо добавлять комментарий `ассоциация:ссылка_на_оригинал` под сообщением.
- Текст про лицензию размещать лучше внизу сообщения, т.к. вверху, всё же, должен быть сам контент.
- Если сообщение сформировано из нескольких сообщений, то указывать всех авторов (и ссылки на сообщения) списком.
- Сам текст по поводу источника в целом не так важен (можно смотреть по ситуации), главное, чтобы там было 3 вещи:

  1. Ссылка на оригинал.
  2. Имя автора оригинала.
  3. Ссылка на профиль автора оригинала.

Comment: В общем, ничего не изменилось

Comment: @Podushkoved хотя бы просто ссылку на сообщение приложить)

Comment: @Podushkoved насколько я помню, Николай ручками периодически это делает. Это не автоматизировано до сих пор =/

Answer (score 11):

Насколько я понимаю, инструмент ассоциаций опирается в первую очередь на комментарий под сообщением. В этом комментарии как раз должна быть ссылка на первоисточник (если это был перевод). Отсюда вытекает вопрос: есть ли нарушение лицензии, если ссылка указана, но не в самом сообщении, а в комментарии под ним? Собственно, комментарий точно так же виден всем, как и само сообщение.

Другая ситуация: ассоциация не обязана быть именно переводом. Совершенно корректная ситуация наличия двух по сути одинаковых вопросов на разных языках SO и независимо написанных ответов. Такие вопросы можно (и даже нужно) ассоциировать, но требовать наличия в них какой-то ссылки на оригинал некорректно, т.к. фактически никакого оригинала нет — вопросы и ответы писались независимо друг от друга.

Ну и в целом. Чья бы корова мычала. SE взяли и перенесли весь пользовательский контент без лишних разговоров с cc by-sa 3.0 на cc by-sa 4.0. А тут вдруг надо бы как-то озаботиться соблюдением лицензии для ассоциаций.

> [image: очевидный текст из кадра]

Особенно при де-факто отсутствии каких-либо нарушений.

P.S. Если кто видит явное использование перевода пары вопрос-ответ при наличии ассоциации и одновременное отсутствие ссылки на первоисточник, можно флагать такое сообщение — пусть модераторы разбираются. Альтернативно можно добавить комментарий со ссылкой.

А вот [тут](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4998/176217) вовсе не рекомендуется менять что-либо в ответе. А это выкладки из ответа community manager между прочим.

Comment: Самое логичное решение - решить это на уровне движка. Движок уже знает про механизм ассоциаций. Неплохо бы было на его уровне добавлять блок в оригинал (о наличии переводов) и в перевод (ссылка на оригинал).

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica в оригинал [блок добавляется и так](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/311016/339911). В перевод - можно и добавлять. Но надо ещё доказать, что это перевод, а не свои мысли. Если автор, конечно, сам откажется признавать это переводом.

Comment: Добавляется, насколько я понимаю, только для тех, у кого RU локаль, не?

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica 100% гарантию может дать только сотрудник SO. Но похоже, что так. С другой стороны - нафига какому-нибудь Педро из Бразилии знать о наличии перевода QA с enSO на ruSO? Ему мог бы быть интересен португальский вариант в первую очередь.

Comment: Тут просто заголовок темы вводит в заблуждение. Проблема действительно с переводами, а не с ассоциациями как таковыми. Если вы пишете уникальный ответ и ассоциируете с похожим вопросом на EN SO, вам не о чем беспокоиться.

Comment: Я так толком и не понял, что такое *ассоциации* (как физически читатель их видит)? Это перечень вопросов под заголовком "похожие" где-то справа внизу от основного текста?

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight просто конкретно для ассоциаций уже есть механизм на уровне движка. Поэтому отдельно это выделил.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight беспокоиться не о чём в любом случае. По крайней мере относительно того, что касается деятельности на SO.

Comment: @avp не, справа в списке - это похожие вопросы. Совсем другое)

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica, и как его увидеть?

Comment: @avp я имел ввиду "связанные вопросы". Как в текущем вопросе. Это просто список сообщений, на которые ссылки есть. Ассоциации - это что-то вроде [такого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/871121/15479). Если зайти в [оригинальный вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2707322/1991579), то там будет блок информационный сверху.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica, ассоциацию в виде комментария со ссылкой я увидел. В `оригинальном вопросе`, откровенно говоря, ничего такого не разглядел. У меня такое ощущение, что вы обсуждаете нечто, не имеющее отношения к обычным пользователям сайта.

Comment: @avp может в браузере русский язык отключен? https://i.stack.imgur.com/37FJQ.png

Comment: @andreymal, наверное. В любом случае, обычных пользователей все эти права не волнуют.