# Правка меток под переводными с EnSO вопросами

Tags: обсуждение, метки, ассоциация-вопросов, лицензирование

Я раньше как-то более лояльно относился к правкам меток под переводными топиками с EnSO.

Ну изменил, удалил участник ruSO метку под топиком и хорошо, если она действительно не очень соответствует содержанию вопроса. Но после [большого шума](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10211/15479) на [мете EnSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394396/1991579) по соблюдению атрибутов лицензии, появился повод задуматься.

Имеем ли мы право удалять метки в вопросе RuSO, которые были в оригинальном топике EnSO?

Для примера [топик](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1103965/28748) где дважды, разными участниками удалялась метка `wordpress` По большому счету они правы, топик по анимации SVG, wordpress упоминается лишь в связи с добавлением анимации в тему `Elementor` wordpress.

Какие будут ваши мнения?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

А какие тут мнения? Метки никак не связаны с ассоциациями. Даже больше - наши метки отличаются порой относительно enSO. Лицензия касается текстов. А метки - это локальная мета информация сайта.

Так что:

1. Метки можно и **нужно** менять, если так будет лучше для нашего сайта.
2. К лицензии это никак не относится.

Comment: ♦ Благодарю за ответ, стало более, менее понятно, вот это и беспокоило в первую очередь, что  **К лицензии это никак не относится** .

Answer (score 1):

> Для примера топик где дважды, разными участниками удалялась метка
>   wordpress По большому счету они правы

Вот именно. Ни вопрос ни тем более ответ не имеет никакого отношения непосредственно к ВП.

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/tagging:

> Метка – это слово или фраза, описывающие **тему вопрос**а.

Comment: вопрос в другом состоит, - имеем ли мы право удалять оригинальные метки в переводных топиках по ассоциации с EnSO

Comment: И причем тут какие-то "оригинальные" метки на другом по сути ресурсе, для другой ЦА? Кому о них известно, кроме "переводчика"? И что, там не могут ошибиться? К тому же для ВП там не метка, как у нас, а целый отдельный раздел. У нас такого нет. Метка должна соответствовать вопросу. И только это важно.

Comment: на всякий случай, я тебе плюс поставил, минус не мой. Ответ от Андрея я получил, который вполне меня  устроил