# Нормально ли переводить вопрос-ответ с английского SO?

Tags: обсуждение

В процессе блуждания по вопросам наткнулся на довольно полезный вопрос, аналога которого нет на русском подсайте, в связи с чем возник вопрос:

Является ли нормальной практикой переводить довольно высокоценный вопрос и ответ на него с английского SO на русский подсайт? Не получу ли я за это по голове? Требуется ли указывать оригинальный вопрос?

Comment: На оба вопроса ответ -- да

Comment: Почитайте по условиям [соблюдения лицензии](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10211/217579) и вперёд. Примите во внимание, что не обязательно переводить сообшения в найденой вами теме точь-в-точь. Если у вас есть идеи как подать вопрос или ответ к нему лучше, с более убедителным примерами или более развёрнутым пояснениями материала, то просто дайте самоответ без указания источников и оставте комментарий по ассоциации.